# What happens if an existing account tries to sign up in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

Whenever a new user signs up in Firebase Auth (username and password), I am creating an account with same `uid` in Firestore.

What happens though if an existing account goes the wrong route and tries to sign up instead of signing in? I wouldn't like to override the info that is already in the account with default value fields supposed to be set only when creating a new account.

I know I can fetch in Firestore to see if the account associated with the id exists or not, but prior to that, does Firebase Auth give some error if the method `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` is called with an existing `username`? If so, I could tell the user the account already exists and therefore, redirect him/her to the login activity.

Answer (score 0):

according to this documentation, there is an error for existing accounts [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword) 
"`The email address is already in use by another account.`" If you need the error code that is returned from firebase request:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "EMAIL_EXISTS"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "EMAIL_EXISTS"
 }
}
```

But in general, YES, you see an get an exception. **What actually you might need** is this in your code  you can handle that by the object in the  error callback with code "`auth/email-already-in-use`" The who error  object is

```
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password).then(
          (user) => {
          // do your
          },
          (err) => {
            if(err.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use');
              alert('Oops. ' + err.code)
          }
        );
```